# Not able to display the child grid when we click on the parent grid

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

Hi I am using Kendo UI grid for showing the information on hierarchy model (parent child grid model) using mvc 4 . but I am not able to show the child grid when we click on the arrow mark in parent grid ... by uisng this reference [hierarchy Grid Model](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/grid/hierarchy.html)

and this is my view for the kendo UI grid ...

```
@Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jquery")
<script type="text/javascript">   
</script>    
@model IEnumerable<Topco.TopMapp.MVC.Models.CostPageSearch>
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Index";
}    
<h2>Index</h2>
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ 
   @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Topco.TopMapp.MVC.Models.CostPageSearch>()
        .Name("ParentGrids")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("<input id='checkbox' onclick='grdChkBoxClick(this); ' class='chkbxq' type='checkbox' />").Width(30);
            columns.Bound(e => e.CostPage).Width(100);
            columns.Bound(e => e.Description).Width(100);
            columns.Bound(e => e.VendorName).Width(100);
            columns.Bound(e => e.BillTypeDirect).Width(100);
            columns.Bound(e => e.BillTypeWarehouse).Width(100);
            columns.Bound(e => e.VendorName).Width(100);

        })
        .Sortable()
        .Pageable()
        .Scrollable()
        .ClientDetailTemplateId("template")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:430px;" })
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .PageSize(6)
            .Read(read => read.Action("HierarchyBinding_Employees", "CostPageDisplay"))
        )
        .Events(events => events.DataBound("grid_dataBound"))
)
    <script id="template" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
         @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Topco.TopMapp.MVC.Models.ItemsDescriptionModel>()
            .Name("grid_#=EmployeeID#")
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("<input id='checkbox' onclick='grdChkBoxClick(this); ' class='chkbxq' type='checkbox' />").Width(30);
                columns.Bound(o => o.ItemId).Width(100);
                columns.Bound(o => o.ItemDescription).Width(100);
                columns.Bound(o => o.BrandCode).Width(100);
                columns.Bound(o => o.PackSize).Width(100);
            })
           .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
               .Ajax()
               .PageSize(5)
               .Read(read => read.Action("HierarchyBinding_Orders", "CostPageDisplay"))
           )
           .Pageable()
           .Sortable()
           .ToClientTemplate()
   )
    </script>
<script>
    function grid_dataBound() {
        this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row").first());
        //alert('1');
    }
</script>
```

and the below Image that I would like to show

[image]

but i am getting image at the moment like this

[image]

would any one have any idea why I am getting this one , Do i need to change any width of parent grid row .....Pls suggest me any ideas....
Many thanks...

**EDIT** : new Image but only getting first row (child grid) not able to see another row child grids...( I am using this moving rows from one grid to another grid that only checked rows need to moved to another grid ...)

```
@using (Html.BeginForm())
{ 
   @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Topco.TopMapp.MVC.Models.CostPageSearch>()
        .Name("ParentGrids")
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("<input id='checkbox' onclick='grdChkBoxClick(this); ' class='chkbxq' type='checkbox' />").Width(30);
            columns.Bound(e => e.CostPage).Width(100);
            columns.Bound(e => e.Description).Width(100);
            columns.Bound(e => e.VendorName).Width(100);
            columns.Bound(e => e.BillTypeDirect).Width(100);
            columns.Bound(e => e.BillTypeWarehouse).Width(100);
            columns.Bound(e => e.VendorName).Width(100);    
        })
        .Sortable()
        .Pageable()
        .Scrollable()
        .ClientDetailTemplateId("template")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:480px;" })
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .PageSize(6)
            .Read(read => read.Action("HierarchyBinding_Employees", "CostPageDisplay"))
        )
        .Events(events => events.DataBound("dataBound"))
)
    <script id="template" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
         @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Topco.TopMapp.MVC.Models.ItemsDescriptionModel>()
            .Name("grid_#=CostPage#")
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("<input id='checkbox' onclick='grdChkBoxClick(this); ' class='chkbxq' type='checkbox' />").Width(30);
                columns.Bound(o => o.ItemId).Width(100);
                columns.Bound(o => o.ItemDescription).Width(100);
                columns.Bound(o => o.BrandCode).Width(100);
                columns.Bound(o => o.PackSize).Width(100);
            })
           .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
               .Ajax()
               .PageSize(5)
               .Read(read => read.Action("HierarchyBinding_Orders", "CostPageDisplay"))
           )
           .Pageable()
           .Sortable()
           .ToClientTemplate()
   )
    </script>
<script>
    function dataBound() {
        this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row").first());
        //alert('1');
    }
</script>        
    <input id="btnMove" type="button" value="Move" />        
   @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Topco.TopMapp.MVC.Models.CostPageSearch>()
        .Name("ParGrids")       
        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("<input id='checkbox' onclick='grdChkBoxClick(this); ' class='chkbxq' type='checkbox' />").Width(30);
            columns.Bound(e => e.CostPage).Width(70);
            columns.Bound(e => e.Description).Width(70);
            columns.Bound(e => e.VendorName).Width(70);
            columns.Bound(e => e.BillTypeDirect).Width(70);
            columns.Bound(e => e.BillTypeWarehouse).Width(70);
            columns.Bound(e => e.OrderType).Width(70);   
        })
        .autoBind(false);
        .Sortable()  
        .Pageable()
        .Scrollable()       
        .ClientDetailTemplateId("DestinationTemplate")
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:480px;" })
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
            .Ajax()
            .PageSize(5)
            .Read(read => read.Action("HierarchyBinding_Employees", "CostPageDisplay"))
        )
        .Events(events => events.DataBound("dataBound"))
)
    <script id="DestinationTemplate" type="text/kendo-tmpl">
         @(Html.Kendo().Grid<Topco.TopMapp.MVC.Models.ItemsDescriptionModel>()
            .Name("grid_=EmployeeID")
            .autoBind(false);
            .Columns(columns =>
            {
                columns.Template(@<text></text>).ClientTemplate("<input id='checkbox' onclick='grdChkBoxClick(this); ' class='chkbxq' type='checkbox' />").Width(30);
                columns.Bound(o => o.ItemId).Width(70);
                columns.Bound(o => o.ItemDescription).Width(70);
                columns.Bound(o => o.BrandCode).Width(70);
                columns.Bound(o => o.PackSize).Width(70);
            })
            .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
               .Ajax()             
               .PageSize(6)
               .Read(read => read.Action("HierarchyBinding_Orders", "CostPageDisplay"))
           )
           .Pageable()
           .Sortable()
           .ToClientTemplate()
   )
    </script>
<script>
    function dataBound() {
        this.expandRow(this.tbody.find("tr.k-master-row").first());
        //alert('1');
    }
</script>

}
```

pls find the attachments here ..
for this code

[image]

Comment: Your  `.Name("grid_#=EmployeeID#")` is invalid because as far as I can see you don't have property called `EmployeeID` try with your "id"  `.Name("grid_#=CostPage#")`

Comment: I am binding same itemDescriptionModel(child grid) with every row of parentgrid irrespective of Id that is what I have done in previous and attached first image (its working) but when i changed column names in every grid its not working ....

Comment: Then this is your problem. Every grid should have an unique `Name`. So if you want to display the same grid in every row you should generate them unique names...

Comment: how can i generate new name for every grid and later i need to access the all grids using javascript

Comment: @nemesv my aim is  moving checked  rows from one  parent grid to another  parent grid along with child grid rows also that only checked rows need to moved for this purpose i have implemented the above code , would you pls look at my Edit ...